# Как вывести ряд в формате сектора в конструкторе visual composer wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, плагин

Есть сайт на **wordpress** с установленным конструктором [visual composer](https://codecanyon.net/item/visual-composer-page-builder-for-wordpress/242431) 5ой серии. В четверной серии можно было выбирать формат ряда, как сектор *grid*

[image: 4 серия]
[image: 5 серия]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То, что раньше называлось in grid, теперь называется "По умолчанию". Такой ряд будет "в  сетке". Остальные пункты Row Stretch растянут ряд (и, если надо, контент) на всю ширину экрана.

Comment: да, только почему-то настройки старого композера не переносятся, вот я и подумал, что нет сеточного рассположения

Comment: Странно. Я обновлял на нескольких сайтах 4.12 до 5.0 и не встретил никаких проблем

Comment: у меня настройки с плагина встроенного в тему. его отключили удалил и поставил отдельный плагин - часть подтянулось автоматом, а частности нет, причем лишние параметры удалил тоже

Comment: Если форки visual composer, то могут быть проблемы, да

Comment: Если ответ помог, его можно отметить как принятый. Это поможет сориентироваться другим пользователям StackOverflow.